# lambda calculus question - concrete

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have the following

```
(f.x.f(f x))(y.y+1) = x.(y.y+1)((y.y+1) x)
= x.(y.y+1)(x+1)
= x.x+1+1
```

I don't understand why is it ok the last transformation? 
Shouldn't it be `x.(y.y+1)(x+1)= y+1`? Why can he get rid of the `y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(y . y + 1)` is applied to its argument `(x + 1)`, so it's substituted for `y` to give `((x + 1) + 1)`.

I don't see how you come up with `x . (y . y + 1)(x + 1)= y + 1`. `y` only exists in the scope of the inner function.